# What if there are different numbers of command line arguments; how can I deal with it in C?

Tags: c, linux

```
// test.c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   printf("%s \n", argv[1]);
   printf("%s \n", argv[2]);
}
```

what if I wanna enter

```
gcc -o test test.c
./test gs -ef
```

or

```
./test ls
```

and so on

When I put in only one argument (ex. ./test date) there is an error message like this (Segmentation fault (core dumped))

When there can come two arguments or one argument in kind like this multiple situations,
How can I code that doesn't print error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argc`: Number of arguments passed.

`argv`: Two-dimensional array that has the arguments passed.

Note that the zeroth position in `argv` is reserved for the program name, so for example you compiled using `gcc -o test test.c`, `argv[0]` will contain `test`. You could then use `argc` to loop through `argv` like so:

```
while (argc >= 0) {
    printf("%s \n", argv[argc]);
    argc--;
}
```

This will of cause print the list of arguments backwards ending with the program name.

Comment: `argv` is not a 2D array; it is an array of `char *`.  A 2D array is 'rectangular' — it has the same length in the second dimension in each row.  The argument vector (`argv`) does not.

Comment: Your loop attempts to print a null pointer on the first iteration (because `argv[argc] == NULL`).  You're also printing the arguments last to first rather than first to last.  It would probably be better to use `for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) printf("%d: [%s]\n", i, argv[i]);` where the square brackets around `%s` make it easier to see leading and trailing white space, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler of cause. It's been some time since I actually coded in C. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `argc` argument to check the number of arguments and use elements of `argv` only if there are enough arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (argc > 1) printf("%s \n", argv[1]);
   if (argc > 2) printf("%s \n", argv[2]);
}
```